# Refreshing div periodically to check if there are new entries in the table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have created a relatively simple "ideas board" in PHP/jQuery/MySQL.

On page load the div **#chat** pulls the current entries in the database.

```
<div id="chat">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * from idea ORDER BY id DESC;";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);

    if($result->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($result))
    {
        foreach ($result as $row) 
        {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $idea = $row['idea'];

        echo '<span class="idea"><strong>' . $row['title'] . "</strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;" . $row['idea'] . '&nbsp;<a class="delete" href="">[Delete]</a></span>';
        }
    }
  ?>
    </div>
```

However I'd like it to be refreshed periodically using:

```
<body onload="setInterval('chat.update()', 1000)">
```

The below example details how it can be done using a text file, how would I do it with querying a database (the example was found at http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/)?

```
//Updates the chat
function updateChat() {
    if(!instanse){
        instanse = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: {'function': 'update','state': state,'file': file},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.text){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                        $('#chat-area').append($("

                        "+ data.text[i] +"

                        "));
                    }   
                }
                document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                instanse = false;
                state = data.state;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
    }
}
```

I expect certain rows to be deleted as well, so on top of entries being appended, I'd also like some to be removed.

It should simulate a real-time conversation.

Comment: You could just set the timeout in the complete callback function of your ajax request

Comment: @roasted Could you show me an example?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/Chat.zip download files from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724055/long-polling-really) technique to update your chat.

eg:

```
//Updates the chat
function updateChat() {
    if(! instance){
        instance = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: {function: 'update', state: state, file: file},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.text){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                        $('#chat-area').append($("

                        "+ data.text[i] +"

                        "));
                    }   
                }
                document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                instance = false;
                state = data.state;
            },
            complete: function(){
               setTimeout(
                    updateChat, /* Request next message */
                    10000 /* ..after 10 seconds */
                );                
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //display you error message               
            },
            timeout: 10000 //Timeout is necessary to prevent chaining of unsuccessful ajax request    
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) library to implement server to client notifications and/or real time communication in both directions.